# WordPress bug appears with a custom shortcode function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have created a simple custom plugin that groups the posts into categories:

```
function custom_category_loop()
{
    // Grab all the categories from the database that have posts.
    $categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name&order=ASC');
    // Loop through categories
    foreach ( $categories as $category )
    {
        // Display category name
        echo '<h2 class="post-title">' . $category->name . '</h2>';
        echo '<div class="post-list">';
        // WP_Query arguments
        $args = array(
            'cat' => $category->term_id,
            'orderby' => 'term_order',
        );
        // The Query
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // The Loop
        if ( $query->have_posts() )
        {
            while ( $query->have_posts() )
            {
                $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                <?php
            } // End while
        } // End if
        echo '</div>';
        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } // End foreach
}
add_shortcode( 'my_posts_grouped', 'custom_category_loop' );
```

I have then created a page and added the single line

```
[my_posts_grouped]
```

My WordPress installation is a multi-site installation, with all pages using the same theme, as I have the same site but in different languages (and URLs).

My problem is that on all my sites, except the one site, the shortcode works as perfectly. On only one site the code is outputted before the header AND inside the body page.

Any ideas why and how to fix this?

Comment: What's the difference in code/markup with that one site?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress shortcodes must *return* data (rather than printing directly to screen using `echo` or similar).

From the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode):

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce output of any kind. **Shortcode functions should return the text** that is to be used to replace the shortcode. **Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results.** This is similar to the way filter functions should behave, in that they should not produce expected side effects from the call, since you cannot control when and where they are called from.

The fact your code is only breaking on one website and not all of them, I would put down to luck.

An updated version of your code that uses `return` instead of the multiple `echo` calls, which should fix your problem:

```
function custom_category_loop()
{
    // String to return
    $html = '';

    // Grab all the categories from the database that have posts.
    $categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name&order=ASC');
    // Loop through categories
    foreach ( $categories as $category )
    {
        // Display category name
        $html .= '<h2 class="post-title">' . $category->name . '</h2>';
        $html .= '<div class="post-list">';
        // WP_Query arguments
        $args = array(
            'cat' => $category->term_id,
            'orderby' => 'term_order',
        );
        // The Query
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // The Loop
        if ( $query->have_posts() )
        {
            while ( $query->have_posts() )
            {
                $query->the_post();
                $html .= '<div><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></div>';
            } // End while
        } // End if
        $html .= '</div>';
        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();

        // Return the HTML string to be shown on screen
        return $html;
    } // End foreach
}
add_shortcode( 'my_posts_grouped', 'custom_category_loop' );
```